# How to modify picture in Shell to show notification badge?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, badge

Currently I am developing my first cross platform mobile App with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2019.
I use a shell with icons for navigation (very basic).

My next challenge: If there are new notifications, a red bubble shall appear on top of the corresponding navigation point.

It should include the number of new notifications.

Example:

[image]

If there are no notifications, there should not be any bubble.
I tried to solve it by generating a png which includes the right number, but this way seems to be very slow and consuming much time to develop.

I feel like there should be any built-in way to add this behavior.
I am happy for any advice, thanks in advance!

Edit:

The Code I use is basically from the visual studio example.

I have a file AppShell.xaml:

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
        <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
            <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabBar" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>

<!-- Your Pages -->
<TabBar>
    <Tab Title="Browse" Icon="tab_feed.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ItemsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="About" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AboutPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <Tab Title="Info" Icon="tab_about.png">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:InfoPage}" />
    </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

Comment: this is called a "badge" and there are many ways you can approach it.  Since you haven't shown us what kind of navigation you're using it's hard to give a specific suggestion, but start by reading this - https://alexdunn.org/2017/03/15/xamarin-controls-badgeview/

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer! The badge is definetly what I need. I updated my question and gave the code snippets. Can you give me a hint how to insert the badge?

Comment: there is a plugin to add tab badges to Forms apps, but it does not work with Shell.  There is a PR for adding this to shell that includes a workaround renderer to enable it now.  See https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BadgeView` from [XamarinCommunityToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit) package as follow:

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
...
<xct:BadgeView BackgroundColor="Red" BadgePosition="TopRight" BorderColor="Transparent"
               Text="{Binding BadgeCount}" FontSize="10" Padding="0" TextColor="White">
    <Image Source="Bell.png" xct:IconTintColorEffect.TintColor="blue"/>
</xct:BadgeView>
```

[image]

Most important here is the `Text` property which is bound to `BadgeCount` of type `int` which of course represent the number displayed in your badge.

When it is equals to 0 then automatically the badge becomes invisible, it will appears again once the value is **>0**, so be sure it doesn't go **<0** unless it is intended by your requirements.

As a side note you can customize the badge psotion: `BadgePosition`, `FontSize`, `FontAttributes`, `BorderColor`, `HasShadow`...

For Anyone interested or curious about this package there is a sample project in [XamarinCommunityToolkit GitHub Repo](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Meanwhile my need to implement this is gone, therefore I will not test it right now, even through it looks very well.